# PyQt не работает кнопка

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Пишу проект работающий с `pymongo` и `PyQt5`.
Интерфейс сделан в отдельном файле через `Qt Designer` и конвертирован в `.py` файл.

Хочу привязать кнопки к функциям. При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.
В шелле команды выполняются как положено.

Файл **main.py**

```
import pymongo
import pprint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from gui import Ui_MainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
import sys
connection = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
database = connection['IITUabiturients']
collection = database['List']
 

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.namesearchpushButton.clicked.connect(self.namesearch)
        self.IDsearchpushButton.clicked.connect(self.IDsearch)
        self.IDdeletepushButton.clicked.connect(self.IDdelete)
        self.sortpushButton.clicked.connect(self.sort)
        self.filterpushButton.clicked.connect(self.filter)
        self.addpushButton.clicked.connect(self.add)
    "def initUI(self):"
        
    def namesearch(self):
        searchname = self.namelineEdit.text()

    def IDsearch(self):
        searchID = self.IDEdit.text()
        
    def IDdelete(self):
        deleteID = self.deletelineEdit.text()

    def sort(self):
        sortoption = str(sortcombobox.currentText())  
  
    def filter(self):
        filteroption = str(filtercombobox.currentText())

    def add(self):
        addname = self.addnamelineEdit.text()
        adddate = self.adddatelineEdit.text()
        addcity = self.addcitylineEdit.text()
        addstudy = self.addstudylineEdit.text()
        addgrade = self.addgradelineEdit.text()
        addgold = self.addgoldlineEdit.text()
        addproject = self.addprojectlineEdit.text()
        addolimp = self.addolimplineEdit.text()
        adddict = {}
        adddict["ФИО"]=addname
        adddict["Дата Рождения"]=adddate
        adddict["Город"]=addcity
        adddict["Школа/Колледж"]=addstudy
        adddict["Балл ЕНТ"]=addgrade
        adddict["Наличие Алтын Белгi"]=addgold
        adddict["Победа в международном проекте"]=addproject
        adddict["Победа в олимпиадах"]=addolimp
        addid = collection.insert_one(adddict)
        rawtable = collection.find()
        prettytable = pprint.pprint(rawtable)
        self.outputtextEdit.insertPlainText(prettytable)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали класс `MainWindow`, но никак с ним не взаимодействуете. Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import re
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import pymongo
import pprint

from gui import Ui_MainWindow   


connection = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
database = connection['IITUabiturients']
collection = database['List']
 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                                                # +
...

        self.outputtextEdit.insertPlainText(prettytable)
  
  
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                                                 # <<<----
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**

Чтобы избавиться от ошибки

> self.namesearchpushButton.clicked.connect(self.namesearch) AttributeError:
>
> 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'namesearchpushButton' namesearchpushButton

Сделайте так и ничего бльше менять не надо:

```
...
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
  
        self.setupUi(self)
...
```

Comment: @HYPERDRYVO я же вам написал  `super().__init__()`

Comment: Вот такая ошибка
  File "D:\MongoDB Project\Code.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.namesearchpushButton.clicked.connect(self.namesearch)
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'namesearchpushButton'
namesearchpushButton это Objectname кнопки настраивал в QTDesigner

Comment: @HYPERDRYVO  1. вы не показали модуль `gui.py`. 2. Вы хотите, чтобы вам исправили сразу все ошибки, не воспроизводя ваш пример? 3. Замените `self.namesearchpushButton.clicked.connect(self.namesearch)` на `self.ui.namesearchpushButton.clicked.connect(self.namesearch)` и т.д. 4. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Братан, можно с тобой как нибудь связаться? Я 2ой день мучаюсь, не могу сделать связь кода `PyCharm` с шаблоном в `Qt Designer`, также, пытаюсь сделать конвертацию, то есть, все то что ты уже сделал. Хелпани плиз, я тоже новичок.
Я знаю что нельзя просить помощи в ответе, но ты не указал никаких контактных данных чтобы я мог написать тебе напрямую

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. 
Если у вас есть вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку [ask].